# Using 3d sparse input with partial shape in Keras/Tensorflow gives error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sparse-matrix

I am trying to create a dense neural network where my input is a sparse 3d matrix. When converted to a dense matrix the shape is `(2, None, n)` (where `n` is a number of features and is fixed.) My keras architecture works fine when I am using dense inputs. However, to save memory I am trying to use sparse tensors as input.

Here is my code

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.keras.Input(batch_shape=(2,None,5))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[x])
model.compile(loss='mse')
print(model.summary())

dummy_input = np.random.random((2,10,5))
dummy_sp = tf.sparse.from_dense(dummy_input)

dummy_output= np.random.random((2,10,1))

model.fit(x=dummy_sp, y=dummy_output, epochs=1)
```

The above code works fine when I use the `x=dummy_input`. Howeverm when I switch to the sparse inputs `dummy_sp` then I get the following error

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(2, None, 5)]            0

 dropout (Dropout)           (2, None, 5)              0

 dense (Dense)               (2, None, 1)              6

=================================================================
Total params: 6
Trainable params: 6
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\099391\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\NP_E-QSI\srcc\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    model.fit(x=dummy_sp, y=dummy_output, epochs=1)
  File "C:\Users\099391\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\099391\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1147, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\099391\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\099391\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\099391\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\099391\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 859, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\099391\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "dropout" (type Dropout).

    Failed to convert elements of SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("model/Cast:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("stack:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int64)) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.

    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x000002423CD78E20>
      • training=True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [tf-documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input), you can still pass the `sparse` tensor even if the `sparse` argument is set as `False`, as long as the input data is a sparse matrix.

> sparse : A boolean specifying whether the placeholder to be created is sparse. Only one of 'ragged' and 'sparse' can be True. **Note that, if sparse is False, sparse tensors can still be passed into the input - they will be densified with a default value of 0.**

```
input = tf.keras.Input(batch_shape=(2,None,5), sparse=False)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[x])
print(model.summary())
# OK
```

### Update

Based on the comment below.

```
class toDense(keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, input):
        if isinstance(input, tf.sparse.SparseTensor):
            return tf.sparse.to_dense(input)
        return input
```

Place it right after `Input` and before the `Dropout` layer of the above model. Like,

```
input = tf.keras.Input(batch_shape=(2,None,5))
x = toDense()(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
...
```

Next, you can do

```
dummy_input = np.random.random((2,10,5))
dummy_sp = tf.sparse.from_dense(dummy_input)
dummy_output= np.random.random((2,10,1))

model(dummy_sp).shape 
>> TensorShape([2, 10, 1])

model.compile(loss='mse')
model.fit(x=dummy_sp, y=dummy_output, epochs=1)
1/1 [=====] - 0s 416ms/step - loss: 0.2746
```

Comment: have you run the above code? it should run properly. Are you facing the error when you pass your actual input data?

Comment: Yep, I tried the above code. I did not get any errors during model compilation. But I got the error I pasted above when passing inputs.

Comment: Okay. So, can you add some dummy input that matches your actual input? Also please update ur Q. with this information. Because, at first, the error that you mentioned was coming from the model compilation.

Comment: Updated the question with sample dummy and dense inputs along with the corresponding traceback error

Comment: Okay, I can now reproduce your error. It seems a bug to me and I think you should raise an issue on GitHub. For a workaround, for now, you can convert the input sparse tensor to dense right after the input layer.

Comment: I tried that too but still getting error

Comment: update the answer, please check.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know. But again, it would be great if you post on the GitHub issue as it should be doable without such a workaround.

Comment: Yep. Apparently there was an issue on GitHub. But it was closed since it was working for 2d sparse array. I posted my comment on that.